# Pass searched query to another view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a small and simple Question and Answer Web App and I am trying to implement a search page.

- I have successfully created a search page.

When i search question title than results are showing fine below the search field.

BUT I am trying to show the answers of the searched tag on another page.

models.py

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    tags = TaggableManager()

class Answers(models.Model):
    quest = models.ForeignKey(Questions,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')

    if query:
        objs = Questions.objects.filter(tags__name__icontains=query)

    context = {'objs': objs}

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

search.html

```
            {% for qas in objs %}
            {{ qas.title }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for ans in answer %}
            {{ ans.ans }}
            {% endfor %}
```

This view is showing answers in single page ( In searched pages ).

I will appreciate your Help. Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to add query to context of `search` view to link corresponding answers:

```
def search(request):
    ...
    context = {'objs': objs,'query':query}

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

Then you can create `search_answer` view, pass query as an argument and filter `Answer` model according to that query:

```
def search_answer(request, query):
    if query:
        answers = Answers.objects.filter(quest__tags__name__icontains=query)
        
    context = {'answers': answers}
    return render(request, 'search_answer.html', context)
```

Update urls file to pass query:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('answers/<query>', search_answer, name='search-answer'),
]
```

In `search.html` you can link to answers page as follows:

```
<form  action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text">

            {% for qas in objs %}
                {{ qas.title }}
            {% endfor %}

            <a href="{% url 'search-answer' query=query %}">See answers</a>
</form>
```

Finally in `search_answer.html`, you can show answers with something like this:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
    Question: {{ answer.quest.title }}
    Answer: {{ answer.body }}
{% endfor %}
```